# Find the small value of the following functions

Tags: inequality

Choose $1<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_M<2$ , such that

$$\left|\sum\limits_{i=1}^{M}x_{i}^{2013}\dfrac{1}{\prod\limits_{1\leq p\leq2013\,,\,,p\neq i}(x_{i}-x_{p})}\right|\leq2$$

where $M=100$

Comment: By "choose", do you mean "find"?

Comment: I assume he means $1<x_i<2$. Where $1 \le i \le M$

Comment: That is just the first 100 terms of the Lagrange interpolation formula for $y(x) = x^{2013}$. A way of ensuring this is if it was the full sum is to select the $x_i$ so $x_i^{2013} \le 2$.

Comment: How can I use this interpolation formula? could you please give me some detailed information?